Next.js Image Optimization Error: "The requested resource isn't a valid image" for valid image paths
I am developing a Next.js application (version 14.2.3) and encountering an issue with the next/image component when trying to load images. The error message I receive after build project:
ImageError: The requested resource isn't a valid image for /assets/media/stock/1600x800/slider3.jpg received text/html; charset=utf-8
    at imageOptimizer (C:\Users\User\Downloads\project\node_modules\next\dist\server\image-optimizer.js:637:19)
    at NextNodeServer.imageOptimizer (C:\Users\User\Downloads\project\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:651:20)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    ...
statusCode: 400


This error occurs in my slider component where I use next/image. Below are the relevant parts of my code:
"use client";

import Layout from "@/Layout/Layout";
import websiteData from "@/utils/website_data.json";
import Slider from "@/components/Slider/Slider";
import FeatureSection from "@/components/FeatureSection/FeatureSection";
import GalleryTabs from "@/components/GalleryTabs/GalleryTabs";
import TopCurve from "@/components/Elements/TopCurve/TopCurve";
import BottomCurve from "@/components/Elements/BottomCurve/BottomCurve";
import Image from "next/image";

function Home() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="d-flex flex-column flex-center w-100 min-h-350px min-h-lg-500px px-9 landing-dark-bg bgi-no-repeat bgi-size-contain bgi-position-x-center bgi-position-y-bottom">
        <Image fill src={websiteData.page.home.landingImage} alt="landing" className="position-static"/>
      </div>
      <BottomCurve />
      {/*  another line */}
      <div>
        <TopCurve />
        <div className="pb-15 pt-18 landing-dark-bg">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="text-center mt-15 mb-18" id="achievements" data-kt-scroll-offset="{default: 100, lg: 150}">
              <h3 className="fs-2hx text-white fw-bold mb-5">
                {websiteData.page.home.gallery.title}
              </h3>
              <div className="fs-5 text-gray-700 fw-bold">
                {websiteData.page.home.gallery.description}
              </div>
            </div>
            <Slider images={websiteData.page.home.gallery.images} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <BottomCurve />
      </div>
      {/*  another line */}
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default Home;

Slider Component:
import Image from "next/image";
import { Carousel } from "react-bootstrap";

function Slider({ images }: { images: string[] }) {
  return (
    <Carousel variant="light" className="mb-10" fade>
      {images.map((item) => (
        <Carousel.Item key={item}>
          <Image
            src={item}
            alt="avater"
            className="w-100 rounded"
            layout="responsive"
            width={1480}
            height={480}
          />
        </Carousel.Item>
      ))}
    </Carousel>
  );
}

export default Slider;

and this is my json file website_data.json:
{
  "page": {
    "home": {
      // another line
      "gallery": {
        "title": "title",
        "description": "description",
        "images": [
          "/assets/media/images/slider1.jpg",
          "/assets/media/images/slider4.jpg",
          "/assets/media/images/slider5.jpg"
        ]
      },
       // another line
    }
  }
}

Despite the images being valid and accessible, I am receiving the "text/html; charset=utf-8" error. I've verified the image paths and ensured the images are accessible. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?
Additional Information:

Next.js version: 14.2.3
The issue occurs only for specific images, while others load without any problem.
its happens after building and starting the project


By default Next/Image searches for images in the /public folder of the project which is exposed. Are you serving your files from somewhere else? Because then you have to specify the absolute path to the images.
